# Is it possible to create Annotation which will prevent pojo member initialization runtime?

Tags: java, annotations

Is there a way to prevent following statement inside a class:

```
private String mTest = "";
```

Is it possible to create `Annotation` like `@Null` which would prevent giving fields direct values this way?

So that the following would give me compile error:

```
@Null
private String mTest = "";
```

And this one being okay:

```
@Null
private String mTest;
```

Thanks.

Comment: From were you have found `@Null` annotation? In standard java there is no such one.

Comment: The question is all about creating that @Null annotation :)

Comment: Ahh, OK, so please annotate this situation in title :)

Comment: I think you can't. The annotation processor can not know what value something will have at runtime unless it is [constant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/VariableElement.html). And the assignment of `""` is not integral part of the `mTest` field, it is part of the instance initialization code and you could have put it into an instance initializer block as well